# Reset plugins version cache | pre_set_site_transient_update_plugins

Tags: plugin-development, updates

In my plugin, I use those filters for auto-update and check the license.

```
add_filter( 'pre_set_site_transient_update_plugins', array( &$this, 'check_for_update' ) );
add_filter( 'plugins_api', array( &$this, 'plugin_api_call' ), 10, 3 );
```

But as I see, WordPress calls that filters once, when changed Version tag in my plugin. 
Can anyone explain how I can reset that cache, for update user rules to download a new version of the plugin.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I find a solution. Just need use filter hook `'site_transient_update_plugins'`

So that work

```
add_filter( 'site_transient_update_plugins', array( &$this, 'check_for_update' ) );
add_filter( 'plugins_api', array( &$this, 'plugin_api_call' ), 10, 3 );
```